# Traversing in break point

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Today while debugging i came across some wired situation.

I put break point in example.cs file then in next.cs file and so on.Now I run the application and do some modification in files, I navigate to some other pages.but I forgot where did i put the breakpoint as project is having huge number of pages.
How to go to those break points.I am using visual studio 2010.
ASP.NET C# project.

Thanks for your kind support.

Sanjeev Dutta

Comment: Click F5 to start debug mode. You should also see what looks like a DVD play button on your debug toolbar. There are other icons on this toolbar to navigate the breakpoints.  Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from main menu: Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints